# When I try to press or hover anchor tag it reacts only on some parts

Tags: html, css, hover, uinavigationbar, anchor

I have 3 anchor tags in my navigation and they work only if I click on upper part of tag and sometimes even that does not work.

```css
nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  text-align: end;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  padding: 2rem;
}

nav a {
  margin-right: 4rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border-radius: 45px;
  background-color: #212529;
}

.active {
  background-color: #383f45;
}

nav a:hover {
  background-color: #6C757D;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="/index.html" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="/html/about.html">About Me</a>
  <a href="/html/contact.html">Contact</a>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to empty your browser's cache memory. When I ran the code there was no issue with clicking the anchor tags.

[Browser Caching](https://medium.com/@codebyamir/a-web-developers-guide-to-browser-caching-cc41f3b73e7c)

[How to remove cache memory](https://clear-my-cache.com/en/windows.html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in z-index. When I gave z-index: 1 to  everything was working normally.